# Sqlite query for Adding the total number of votes for each option

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have a result table which is like the following:

```
PollId   UserId   Option1   Option2   Option3   Option4   Option5
1          1        0         1        0            0       0
2          1        0         0        0            0       1
```

First row, userid=1 voted option2 in pollId=2 and userid=1 voted option5 in pollid=2.

Then I have the Polls table:

```
PollId   userId   PollName       OptionName1  OptionName 2   OptionName 3   OptionName 4   
 1         1       Yes/No        Yes              No            null           null
```

and so on up until optionname5.

I want to count the percentage of each option with a specific poll. I just want a starting point on how do I go on about doing this.

On the results activity, I want to show for a poll question which has 4 options as follows:

> ```
> Option 1 (10%)
> Option 2 (20%)
> Option 3 (60%)
> Option 4 (10%)
> ```

Comment: What is Polls table for?

Comment: for storing the poll question with its options.

Comment: results table stores the option user picks for a particular poll

Comment: What is `Poll.userId` for?

Comment: in the polls table, userId corresponds to who created the poll, in the results table, userId corresponds to who voted for the poll.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you should rebuild your database to normalize it:

```
PollId   UserId   OptionNr
1          1        2
2          1        5
```

So your query would just be:

```
SELECT 'Option '||OptionNr, CAST(COUNT()*100/(SELECT COUNT() FROM Result WHERE PoolId=1) AS INT)||'%'
FROM Result
WHERE PoolId=1
GROUP BY OptionNr
ORDER BY OptionNr
```

If you prefer keep your schema - sooner or later you will understand it isn't adequate - you may perform following query:

```
 SELECT 'Option 1', CAST(SUM(Option1)*100/COUNT() AS INT)||'%' FROM Results WHERE PoolId=1
 UNION
 SELECT 'Option 2', CAST(SUM(Option2)*100/COUNT() AS INT)||'%' FROM Results WHERE PoolId=1
 UNION
 SELECT 'Option 3', CAST(SUM(Option3)*100/COUNT() AS INT)||'%' FROM Results WHERE PoolId=1
 UNION
 SELECT 'Option 4', CAST(SUM(Option4)*100/COUNT() AS INT)||'%' FROM Results WHERE PoolId=1
 UNION
 SELECT 'Option 5', CAST(SUM(Option5)*100/COUNT() AS INT)||'%' FROM Results WHERE PoolId=1
```

Comment: thank you. I want to get the results for a specific pollId. So in that case, should I just add WHERE CLAUSE? For example: WHERE PollId='1' etc? Also some polls have 2 options for a yes or no question. While some have more than 2. How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: This is a different problem as `Option 1 (10%)` is not suitable for presenting results. Think about pretended result and ask a new question, if it is too different from this.

Comment: alright cool. I'm using SQLite database FTR, and I have never seen UNION notation before in queries.

Comment: That's because your database is not normalized. Each option is a column instead of a row, so `UNION` must be used in order to rearrange columns.

Comment: Hum... Can't understand why. Maybe a limitation of FTR API?